# Connecting to sql port 83306

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, tcp

Hey to create my system i have to connect to port 83306(i can't change this port).If i only install workbench i can see the database.But since i have to connect to a port greater than 65536 i when i install mysql server i can't connect to this database.Can anyone suggest a way to connect to this database.

i tried to use port 83306 when installing mysql server but it didn't support.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:83306/sampledb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
```

Comment: There is no such thing as 'port 83306'. A port number is 16 bits, unsigned, which means that the maximum value is 65535. So your alleged 'requirement' of  'I have to connect to a port greater than 65536' is infeasible.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use port 3306 .

Comment: The requirement by OP is `But since i have to connect to a port greater than 65536` so it is not a valid answer.

Comment: no i can't since i have to get data from a databse of another system and it's only working for port 83306

Comment: Try set spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:83306/sampledb?useSSL=true

Comment: @michalk *Nothing* is a valid answer, since the requirement stated isn't feasible.

Comment: @jack I agree with your answer, but your comment is futile. Port 83306 does not exist, so it cannot possibly work.

Comment: @user207421 My problem, the port is really not 83306. But the problem is similar.

Comment: @jack No it isn't. The problem is that the OP has an imaginary requirement for an impossible port number. He should use port 3306, as the MySQL designers intended when they reserved it at IANA about 25 years ago, and as your answer already states.

Comment: @user207421 Maybe you are right, but he can only use 83306.

Comment: @jack I *am* right, no two ways about it, see RFC 793, and he most certainly can *not* use port 83306, as it neither does nor can exist. OP is dreaming.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone needs it, found the following info:
https://fusionmiddleware11g.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/message-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-port-out-of-range83306/

> If the port used is greater than 65536, you need to subtract 65536
> from the port to get the result to connect. The port I use here is
> 83306: 83306-65536 = 17770, so I have to use 17770 to connect to the Mysql database.